# SQL Server network configuration

Tags: sql-server, connection-string

I was deploying an old ASP site to a new server and we realized that the site was going really slow. I couldn't figure out what was the cause until I noticed that SQL Server network configuration had this configuration:

- SharedMemory Enabled
- Named pipes Disabled
- TCP/IP Disabled

I enabled the last two and all was fixed instantly. The connection string I'm using is something like this:

```
PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=...;UID=...;PWD=...
```

I'd like to understand why this was happening, and again, the queries to the DB were working just terribly slow.

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK,these should not impact performance

Comment: can you repro this consistently by turning those two off

Comment: are you still facing the issue ?

Comment: You are still using Shared Memory, you can see it by executing the code:select session_id, net_transport
from sys.dm_exec_connections

Comment: Not sure I understand what you meant here.